# Позднее связывание на службах-android

Tags: android, java

Имеется служба со многими методами, есть абстрактные. стало быть эта служба тоже абстрактная. в неё реализован метод onStartCommand, который вызывает определённые методы в зависимости от intent.getAction(). Я реализую эту абстрактную службу двумя классами и onStartCommand не переопределяю. Эти два класса зарегестрированы в манифесте с одинаковым IntentFilter. Какая служба будет запущена становится известно только тогда, когда юзер сделает выбор (нажмёт одну кнопку или другую). Как мне с помощью Intent задать чтобы запускалась нужная служба ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<service android:name="ServerSmsService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.ASmsService.BLUETOOTH_INFO_REQUEST"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.ASmsService.BLUETOOTH_TURN_REQUEST"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.ASmsService.SERVICE_KILL"/>
            <data android:scheme="server"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="ClientSmsService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.ASmsService.BLUETOOTH_INFO_REQUEST"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.ASmsService.BLUETOOTH_TURN_REQUEST"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.ASmsService.SERVICE_KILL"/>
            <data android:scheme="client"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

так можно?

Answer (score 0):

`startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));`

Comment: я рассматривал это, а можно ли запуская неявно сделать то что я хочу ? т.е. startService(new Intent(String action))

Comment: > Как мне с помощью Intent задать чтобы запускалась нужная служба ?

То есть вы хотите указать, какой сервис запускать, но при этом это явно не указывать? Вас ничего не смущает?